# what is hudson.abortexception: script returned exit code -1073741819 in Jenkins and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, groovy, deployment

I have a Jenkins pipeline script which runs both on windows and linux systems. It works fine on linux however, on windows once the test stage is completed the build exits with hudson.abortexception: script returned exit code -1073741819 and the build fails. Does anyone have any idea why is this happening and best way to avoid it?

```
//The exception is occuring after this step runs successfully.
try{
    bat"${workspace}\\env\\python\\python.exe -m coverage run -a setup.py test"
    bat"${workspace}\\env\\python\\python.exe -m coverage xml -i"
}
catch(err){
    echo "Error: ${err}"
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
}
```

In my python script setup.py I am using ThreadPool.

```
tp = ThreadPool(workers)
for module in modules_list:
    tp.apply_async(test_module(module), (path_to_module_reports))
tp.close()
tp.join()
```

I can handle this exception using try and catch but I want to know what is the root cause of this exception and how can I fix it?

Comment: The exit code -1073741819 in hex is 0xC0000005. If you look up this code in Microsoft's documentation (NTSTATUS Values) you will see that it indicates that your program was terminated due to an access violation. This error can occur for a variety of reasons, including de-referencing a NULL pointer or referencing an invalid address. If you are running the jenkins agent as a service then you will have to ensure what user the Jenkin Agent service is running with and ensure that the same user has permission to access that folder.